# Get browser URL magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite

I want to get URL which is passed in the address bar but problem is that in my .htaccess there is a code for the rewrite I don't know for that reason or something else I got other URL which is not matched with my browser URL

Browser URL is
https://www.example.com/category/112-model+name-azx+xza.html

And with this code **"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"**

I got http://www.example.com/azx-xza-asd.html" Which is stored in product detail

I want  https://www.example.com/category/112-model+name-azx+xza.html

Comment: you want to this type of url - www.example.com/category/product.html

Comment: No, I mentioned in question I want URL which I SHow in my address bar.

Comment: www.example.com/product.html

Comment: Can you please provide the htaccess code which does your rewrite, especially if it is not magento standard?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/.*$
    RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9+\(\)']+)-([a-zA-Z0-9+]+)-asd\.html$ /category/index.php?category=category+name&year=$1&make=$2&model=$3&battery=$4 [L]

Comment: Do you have a category directory with an index.php file which is not standard magento? If yes, you have to see what happens there.

Comment: No man, I want URL which I see on the top that's it.

Comment: If you habe custom logic implemented which bypasses Magento routing you have to investigate that way imho. You can't expect one can guess yor customization :-) Anyway you might consider using javascript for that, if it fits to your requirements if the rewriting / routing process serverside doesn't allow the access

Comment: Yes, I check it.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: @magefms not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current url with the following code:

```
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() ->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$url->getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: Sorry @HelgeB but with this code, I get the same result which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currenturl=$storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
```

To get current URL without Query String, add below line:

```
$currenturl = substr($currenturl, 0, strpos($currenturl, "?"));
```

Comment: Sorry got the same Result, not get address bar URL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
$request = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() ->get('\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface');

echo $request->getUriString();
```